# how to download attachments from e-mail and keep original filename? using Python/outlook

Tags: python, outlook, save, attachment, pywin32

I'm trying to download the attachments in an email from outlook using Python and the windows extensions, so far I've tried the following:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('Subfolder')
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast() #open last message
attachments = message.Attachments #assign attachments to attachment variable
attachment = attachments.Item(1)
attachment.SaveASFile("File_name")
```

This code will save the file under the filename: "File_name" . Is there any way I could use the original file name as the file name I'm using to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use the `Attachment.FileName` property (concatenate it with the directory name where you want to save the attachment).

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a filename, just give the location where you want the file to be saved:

```
import os

attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join('c:', 'your_dir_name'))
```